# Yahoo Oauth 2 PHP

Tags: codeigniter, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I'm working on a project where i need to fetch contacts from yahoo mail. and I'm using Oauth2.0. I'm getting `access_token` and all things from here `https:// api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token` via `curl` with passing `grant_type` and all required parameters which is fine. but the problem is `refresh_token` and `xoauth_yahoo_guid` from yahoo I'm redirecting to this url `https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{xoauth_yahoo_guid}/contacts?format=json`. I'm getting this output:-

`{"error":{"@lang":"en-US","@uri":"http://yahoo.com","description":"Not Authorized - Either YT cookies or a valid OAuth token must be passed for authorization","detail":"Not Authorized - Either YT cookies or a valid OAuth token must be passed for authorization"}}`

However I'm working in codeigniter and i need this task to be done in ajax or javascript But I've tried a lot but unfortunately nothing worked out for me. Please help me to get rid out of this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. I just have to send the header

`$headers= array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '.< access_token >,
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );`

with following Code:-

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
    $url = "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts?format=json"; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $output3 = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle
    $finalresult = json_decode($output3);
    echo'<pre>';print_r($finalresult);
```